# CSS checkbox aligns center not left when I look at page in Firefox, works fine in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, css-float

so I have a form that I have multiple input text fields as well as a select box or two and then 3 checkboxes. Everything lines up correctly in Chrome and looks great, then I look at it in firefox and everything except the checkboxes line up, they instead are center aligned in their area rather than being to the left like in Chrome. I have tried putting an extra div around it and everything but nothing seems to break it. Any help or errors that I am not seeing in the code?

**Checkbox on the form**

```
<div class="blueTable"> - this is for the rest of the form and table
<div class="checkbox"> - this is what I put in to override
<label>Is this a letter?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="letter" value="YES" class="checkbox"/>

<label>Return label?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="return" value="YES" class="checkbox"/>                 

<label>Save destination for future shipments?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="save_destination" value="YES" class="checkbox"/>
</div></div>
```

**CSS File**

```
.blueTable input,.blueTable select{
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:4px 2px;
    width:400px;
    margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.checkbox  {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset or normalization file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MfNdF/ is this something you are going for?

.blueTable input gives your checkboxes width of 400 pixels which might cause the problem.

Comment: Sorry didnt tell you but the label is on the left and the box is on the right, that looks good except its the opposite side. In firefox the box lines up in the middle of the 400px width when in chrome it will line up correctly to the left.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/MfNdF/3/. If not then I am not understanding you. Could you please provide a jsfiddle which demonstrates your problem as I am not seeing your problem in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Yes that last jsfiddle is what I am trying at with the labels aligned to the right. So in firefox the boxes would be 200px away from the label but in chrome they are next to each other
-think this saved http://jsfiddle.net/MfNdF/

Comment: Just changed the width in the checkbox div to width:20px!important;

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS and table hybrid layout. To align your page. This may help your web page show up better across more browsers especially ones that are not as CSS compliant as chrome.